# How to I rig a bone to the origin of an object?

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to rig and I want the ball on the wider end of a bone in blender to be in the origin of an object so it's centered.Is their anyway to quickly do this or do I just have to keep moving the bone until I get it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use snapping and the 3d cursor to do this. With the object selected,use Shift-S and choose 'snap cursor to selected'. Once you have the cursor at the obj origin, you can select your bone and enter edit mode, and then select just the end (tail) or tip (head) and Shift- S choosing 'selection to cursor'. Incidentally, if your cursor is already at the origin of your object before you generate the bone, you might find it already orients where you wanted it to begin with.